Pi MO Diagram of Guanidinium Cation
My organic chemistry professor has asked us to draw the pi MO diagram of the guanidinium cation.
I only got as far as the lowest and highest energy orbitals (with zero and three nodal planes respectively). I believe the remaining two would have one and two nodal planes respectively, but I can't figure out how to place them symmetrically in the molecule.
Any help would be appreciated. I've attached some images showing how far I got (nodal planes denoted by dotted lines).
Thanks! 

How many orbitals are you expecting? Are not a, b, d the same ? Have you missed some nodal planes?

@porphyrin I'm expecting four MOs in total; you're right a, b, d are the same but I really couldn't figure out how to draw the nodal planes in this case
